# which extension provide user idea and suggetion in joomla 3.2?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

i am new in joomla i am using joomla 3.2 and i want non-commercial plugin for user idea and suggetion i want extension like this http://screencast.com/t/L8wNWWAdE7
and the http://ideas.joomla.org/forums/84261-joomla-idea-pool is main link of my sacreen cast so please help  me to get this type of extension i was used feedback factory but it require login when guest want to vote so i don't want login system in my site so please suggest me extension for that

Answer (score 4):

Check the Testimonials and Suggestions category in the Joomla Extensions Directory: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/testimonials-a-suggestions

"User Ideas" http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/testimonials-a-suggestions/24422 is Joomla 3.x compatible and non-commercial but it's not clear whether it allows guest submissions.

A couple of other extensions, "Suggest, Vote, Comment, Bribe", http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/testimonials-a-suggestions/11505 and "Ajax Suggestion Box" http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/testimonials-a-suggestions/16263 look like they might be suitable but they aren't Joomla 3.x ready yet.